# How to make a response in Bluetooth module (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I connected my Bluetooth module to the mobile phone and made up a code to communicate between Arduino and mobile through Bluetooth (send messages from Bluetooth module to device and vice versa).

Now I want to make a response, which means that if I send from the mobile "hi" the arduino replies and says "Hello" or whatever.

I have tried tons of codes but none worked, so would anyone please help me?

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial myserial (6,5); 

void setup() {
  myserial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (myserial.available()) {
    Serial.write(+ myserial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    myserial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Another code but making a loop without sending anything

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial myserial(6,5); //Arduino: R:5,T:6; bluetooth: T:5, R:6;

void setup() {
  myserial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (myserial.available()) {
    Serial.write(myserial.read()); 
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    myserial.write(Serial.read());
  }
  for (int i = 0; i=2; i++) {
    myserial.write("hello");
  }
  if (myserial.read() =="n") {
    myserial.write("hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your serial string char by char using the `SerialEvent()` interrupt, then do a String comparison using the `.equals` method. Despite many people will tell you that String types are 'evil' (see [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=444696.0) and [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)) it might be a good solution for making things clearer (and perhaps a bit easier if you don't want to mess with C char strcmp() functions and pointers. In the end, the String type is there for you and I see no reason for not using it in general projects.

Based on the `SerialEvent()` documentation  [[1]](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent), and the String reference [[2]](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/), you could do something like:

```
String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
bool stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    
    //Then you compare the inputString with the word you want to detect using the .equals method from the String class
      if(inputString.equals("Hi"){
          Serial.println("Hello");
      }
    // clear the string for a new comparison:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the hardware serial RX. This
  routine is run between each time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can
  delay response. Multiple bytes of data may be available.
*/
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 1: Of course, you can replace the Serial object from this example code with your own myserial object from the BlueTooth communication.

Comment: Well, thank you for this amazing answer, but the problem is that I am a super beginner and I am not familiar with all of what you have written. But honestly, the code looks amazing xd
So, how can I use this code on my own project, I mean should I define the pins and so or what should I exactly do?
Thank you one more time

Comment: You can literally copy-paste the code I shared with you and change only the part that applies to your `SoftwareSerial()` carefully read line by line and you will see that it is quite simple. Do not panic!